# Как реализовать камеру на pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame, 2d, камера

Недавно начал писать 2D платформер, используя библиотеку pygame, но столкнулся с маленькой проблемой в лице камеры. Ниже приведён код простейшей камеры, которая всегда держит персонажа в центре экрана и передвигает все объекты на карте, основываясь на его действиях. Проблема в том, что иногда камера показывает больше, чем нужно. (Вот в такие моменты) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Буду очень благодарен, если вы предложите варианты доработки нижеприведенного кода или хотя бы концепт иного подхода, удовлетворяющего поставленные цели. Если для решения нужны дополнительные материалы, пишите в комментариях, добавлю всё, что потребуется.

```
# Класс камеры
class Camera:
    # Зададим начальный сдвиг камеры
    def __init__(self, field_size):
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 1
        self.width = field_size[0]
        self.height = field_size[1]

    # Сдвинуть объект obj на смещение камеры
    def apply(self, obj):
        obj.rect.x += self.dx // 2
        obj.rect.y += self.dy // 2
        return obj.rect.x, obj.rect.y

    # Позиционировать камеру на объекте target
    def update(self, target):
        self.dx = (-target.rect.centerx + SIZE[0] // 2)
        self.dy = (-target.rect.centery + SIZE[1] // 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас отображение картинки уже привязано к местоположению камеры, тогда вы можете просто приравнивать координаты камеры к координатам центра игрока (но относительно карты), также если перемещать камеру на расстояние, разделенное на число, то можно добиться плавности камеры, и вот формула, которая может помочь вам:

```
camera.x = round((camera.x-player.x)/10)
camera.y = round((camera.y-player.y)/10)
```

Почему лучше использовать round()?

- Потому что когда игрок будет стоять на месте, камера будет неприятно перемещаться по одному пикселю при местоположении, очень близком к игроку.